# Why Import export of module is giving error as "BlogpostModule' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)" angular 7

Tags: html, typescript, angular7

I have created component within module and trying to output the result with simple html code in 'app.component.html'

When I hover on the code it shows me this error "BlogpostModule' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)"

When I remove the code "". I see the output.

Please help me to fix this blank page.

app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
<app-header></app-header>
<app-banner></app-banner>
<app-blogpost-featured></app-blogpost-featured>
<app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { BlogpostModule } from './blogpost/blogpost.module';
import { CmspageModule } from './cmspage/cmspage.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { BannerComponent } from './banner/banner.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    BannerComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CmspageModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

blogpost.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { BlogpostRoutingModule } from './blogpost-routing.module';
import { BlogpostFeaturedComponent } from './blogpost-featured/blogpost-featured.component';
import { BlogpostListComponent } from './blogpost-list/blogpost-list.component';
import { BlogpostDetailComponent } from './blogpost-detail/blogpost-detail.component';
import { BlogpostRecentComponent } from './blogpost-recent/blogpost-recent.component';
import { CategoriesComponent } from './categories/categories.component';


@NgModule({
   imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BlogpostRoutingModule
  ],
  exports: [
    BlogpostFeaturedComponent
  ],
  declarations: [BlogpostFeaturedComponent, BlogpostListComponent, BlogpostDetailComponent, BlogpostRecentComponent, CategoriesComponent],
  })
export class BlogpostModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include `BlogpostModule` in your `app.module.ts`.

Comment: Thank you Pankaj. I am new to angular. Trying to create a blog site! Thanks a lot. Could you please share your email id for further queries? Thanks again